# "no such column" error when running a SQL query in an Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public DataTable getZiyaretsizPlanListe(int Gun) {

                sql = " SELECT "
                    + " (CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150) then UniteAd  + ' (' + muaSemtBrick.AltBolgeAd + ') '"
                    + " ELSE  UniteAd  + ' (' + [SemtBrick].AltBolgeAd + ')'    END ) AS UniteAd, "  
                    + " Dr.Sabit,   Dr.Unvan + ' ' + Dr.Ad + ' ' + Dr.Soyad AS AdSoyad, ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Kod" 
                    + " FROM ((DoktorZiyaretNone INNER JOIN ((( Doktor AS Dr INNER JOIN AltIht ON Dr.Ihtisas = AltIht.UKod) " 
                    +" LEFT JOIN Semt AS MuaSemt ON Dr.Adres3 = MuaSemt.UKod) "
                    +" LEFT JOIN SemtBrick AS MuaSemtBrick ON MuaSemt.AltBolgeKod = MuaSemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Doktor = Dr.Sabit) " 
                    +" LEFT JOIN ZiyaretEtmemeSebep ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Sebep = ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Sebep)  "
                    +" INNER JOIN ((unite INNER JOIN Semt ON unite.SemtTek = Semt.UKod) "
                    +" INNER JOIN SemtBrick ON Semt.AltBolgeKod = SemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Unite = unite.UniteKod " 
                    +" WHERE Dr.Unite <> 200 And DoktorZiyaretNone.DTarih = "+ Gun ;

                    /*+" UNION "
                    //+" SELECT Dr.Unite as Unite, " +
                    +" SELECT  " 
                    +" EczAd + '(' + [SemtBrick].[AltBolgeAd] + ')' AS UniteAd, Dr.Sabit, Dr.Unvan + ' ' + Dr.Ad + ' ' + Dr.Soyad AS AdSoyad, ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Kod" 
                    +" FROM (DoktorZiyaretNone INNER JOIN (((Doktor AS Dr INNER JOIN AltIht ON Dr.Ihtisas = AltIht.UKod) INNER JOIN unite ON Dr.Unite = unite.UniteKod) INNER JOIN (Semt INNER JOIN SemtBrick ON Semt.AltBolgeKod = SemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON Dr.Adres3 = Semt.UKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Doktor = Dr.Sabit) LEFT JOIN ZiyaretEtmemeSebep ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Sebep = ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Sebep"
                    +" WHERE Dr.Unite = 200 And DoktorZiyaretNone.DTarih = " + Gun ; 
                    +" ORDER BY Dr.Unite ";*/
                Log.d("EDK","getZiyaretsizPlanListe SQL:" + sql);
                return getResult(sql, true);
            }

    public DataTable getResult(String sqlText, boolean showError){
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(context);
            Cursor cursor;
            try {
                cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlText, null);
                if (cursor!=null)
                {dataTable = new DataTable(context, sqlText);
                dataTable.setDataSource(cursor, sqlText);
                cursor.close();}

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e("LOG ERROR", e.getMessage());
                if(showError){
                    Util.setException(context,  e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

when i execute sql in getZiyaretsizPlanListe i get error from LogCat

```
06-24 14:55:47.167: E/SQLiteLog(636): (1) no such column: SemtBrick.AltBolgeAd
06-24 14:55:47.167: E/LOG ERROR(636): no such column: SemtBrick.AltBolgeAd (code 1): , 
while compiling: SELECT  (CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod=150) then UniteAd  +
 ' (' + muaSemtBrick.AltBolgeAd + ') ' ELSE  UniteAd  + ' (' + [SemtBrick].AltBolgeAd + ')'     END ) AS UniteAd, 
 Dr.Sabit,  Dr.Unvan + ' ' + Dr.Ad + ' ' + Dr.Soyad AS AdSoyad, ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Kod FROM 
 ((DoktorZiyaretNone INNER JOIN ((( Doktor AS Dr INNER JOIN AltIht ON Dr.Ihtisas = AltIht.UKod) 
 LEFT JOIN Semt AS MuaSemt ON Dr.Adres3 = MuaSemt.UKod)  LEFT JOIN SemtBrick AS MuaSemtBrick ON MuaSemt.AltBolgeKod = MuaSemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Doktor = Dr.Sabit) 
 LEFT JOIN ZiyaretEtmemeSebep ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Sebep = ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Sebep)   INNER JOIN ((unite INNER JOIN Semt ON unite.SemtTek = Semt.UKod)  
 INNER JOIN SemtBrick ON Semt.AltBolgeKod = SemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Unite = unite.UniteKod  WHERE Dr.Unite <> 200 And DoktorZiyaretNone.DTarih = 41449
06-24 14:55:47.187: W/System.err(636): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: SemtBrick.AltBolgeAd (code 1): ,
 06-24 14:55:47.187: W/System.err(636): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: SemtBrick.AltBolgeAd (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  (CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod=150) then UniteAd  + ' (' + muaSemtBrick.AltBolgeAd + ') ' ELSE  UniteAd  + ' (' + [SemtBrick].AltBolgeAd + ')'    END ) AS UniteAd,  Dr.Sabit,    Dr.Unvan + ' ' + Dr.Ad + ' ' + Dr.Soyad AS AdSoyad, ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Kod FROM ((DoktorZiyaretNone INNER JOIN ((( Doktor AS Dr INNER JOIN AltIht ON Dr.Ihtisas = AltIht.UKod)  LEFT JOIN Semt AS MuaSemt ON Dr.Adres3 = MuaSemt.UKod)  LEFT JOIN SemtBrick AS MuaSemtBrick ON MuaSemt.AltBolgeKod = MuaSemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Doktor = Dr.Sabit)  LEFT JOIN ZiyaretEtmemeSebep ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Sebep = ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Sebep)   INNER JOIN ((unite INNER JOIN Semt ON unite.SemtTek = Semt.UKod)  INNER JOIN SemtBrick ON Semt.AltBolgeKod = SemtBrick.AltBolgeKod) ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Unite = unite.UniteKod  WHERE Dr.Unite <> 200 And DoktorZiyaretNone.DTarih = 41449
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
06-24 14:55:47.199: W/System.err(636):  at BusinessObjects.GenelSql.getResult(GenelSql.java:88)
```

Please help me

Comment: @MonadNewb: Yeah, it was there when I voted to close as duplicate. @ user2515613 it's better to edit existing questions to be more useful and answerable instead of opening new questions with practically the same content. As of now, this question is too localized - "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors"

Comment: @laalto Since the old question has been deleted, you might want to delete the comment here. I'll clean up my own comments as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing one parenthesis in excess:

```
(CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150)
```

should be

```
(CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150
```

Also in your From part you have one left parenthesis in excess.
The error that you are getting (no such column: SemtBrick.AltBolgeAd) should be corrected after this, providing the column exists.

Does this work for you:

```
        sql = " SELECT "
            + " CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150 then UniteAd  + ' (' + muaSemtBrick.AltBolgeAd + ') '"
            + " ELSE  UniteAd  + ' (' + [SemtBrick].AltBolgeAd + ')'    END AS UniteAd, "  
            + " Dr.Sabit,   Dr.Unvan + ' ' + Dr.Ad + ' ' + Dr.Soyad AS AdSoyad, ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Kod" 
            + " FROM DoktorZiyaretNone "
            + " INNER JOIN Doktor AS Dr ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Doktor = Dr.Sabit " 
            + " INNER JOIN AltIht ON Dr.Ihtisas = AltIht.UKod "
            + " LEFT JOIN Semt AS MuaSemt ON Dr.Adres3 = MuaSemt.UKod "
            + " LEFT JOIN SemtBrick AS MuaSemtBrick ON MuaSemt.AltBolgeKod = MuaSemtBrick.AltBolgeKod " 
            + " LEFT JOIN ZiyaretEtmemeSebep ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Sebep = ZiyaretEtmemeSebep.Sebep "
            + " INNER JOIN unite ON DoktorZiyaretNone.Unite = unite.UniteKod "
            + " INNER JOIN Semt ON unite.SemtTek = Semt.UKod "
            + " INNER JOIN SemtBrick ON Semt.AltBolgeKod = SemtBrick.AltBolgeKod "
            + " WHERE Dr.Unite <> 200 And DoktorZiyaretNone.DTarih = " + Gun ;
```

Comment: (CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150) i think this is the same for solution i coulnt find (CASE  WHEN ([unite].UniteKod)=150))

Comment: had a mistake, just refreshed

Comment: now i get Unite.UniteAd no such column error i get when i remove case statement i check and i got UniteAd col in the result